# how to install amd rx vega 64 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, radeon, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I'm totally new to Ubuntu, and I have tried to install my AMD RX Vega 64 the way it says on AMD's site, but I can't make it work. I have done this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot

cd /tmp
tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.40-483984.tar.xz.tar

cd amdgpu-pro-17.30-NNNNNN
./amdgpu-pro-install –y
sudo reboot

sudo usermod -a -G video $ my user

sudo apt install -y rocm-amdgpu-pro

echo 'export LLVM_BIN=/opt/amdgpu-pro/bin' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/amdgpu-pro.sh
```

This is what the terminal shows me when I try to see if my GPU is installed:

```
~$ dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
Deseado=desconocido(U)/Instalar/eliminaR/Purgar/retener(H)
| Estado=No/Inst/ficheros-Conf/desempaqUetado/medio-conF/medio-inst(H)/espera-disparo(W)/pendienTe-disparo
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/requiere-Reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo)
||/ Nombre         Versión      Arquitectura Descripción
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  amdgpu-pro     17.40-483984 amd64        Meta package to install amdgpu Pr

~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       versión: c1
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuración: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       recursos: irq:27 memoria:c0000000-cfffffff memoria:dfe00000-dfffffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memoria:fde00000-fde7ffff memoria:c0000-dffff

-$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               0

~$ sudo lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64] (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 0b36
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at dfe00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at ee00 [size=256]
    Memory at fde00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] #15
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
    Capabilities: [320] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: AMD
client glx vendor string: AMD
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.

~$ lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64] (rev c1)
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The missing OpenCL platform? Otherwise, it looks like your Vega card is working, and is using the proprietary drivers.

Comment: im trying to use miner programs and none of them (even minergate gui) recognize the gpu, and in "adittional drivers" does not appear the driver or the GPU, i have uninstalled the driver and it shows the same: ~$ lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64] (rev c1)

Comment: I think you might still be missing a package. Instead of `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep amdgpu` instead. Also, it would be easier to read if you broke up each block of information into different block quotes.

Comment: ~$ dpkg -l | grep amdgpu
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                        2.4.83-1~16.04.1                             amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386                         2.4.83-1~16.04.1                             i386         Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04         1.3.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver

Comment: sorry i don't know how to paste the info has seen in the terminal

Comment: You can wrap the content using `pre` as if it was an HTML.

Comment: @dobey the proper way is to select the text and press the `{}` button in the editor, which adds four spaces to the beginning of each line.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I do not agree, but this is not the proper place to have such a discussion.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell your graphics adapter is unsupported by the driver.